# How to verify apk has compress with zopfli or not

Tags: android, zipalign, zopfli

I use buildToolsVersion 26.0.3 with android studio 3.0.1 to generate signed apk

1. how to verify that the apk is compress with zopfli or not ?
2. how to disable zopfli compress when execute zipalign in android studio ?

Comment: On a side note it's apparently no longer recommended to compress your APKs with zopfli: https://medium.com/google-developers/smallerapk-part-1-anatomy-of-an-apk-da83c25e7003

Comment: Yes, so that I want to disable zopfli in android studio